# TSQL: Check that a varchar can be converted to a number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to test whether the value of the variable can be converted to a numeric value.

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(50)
SET @var1 = '1'

IF(ISNUMERIC(@var1) = 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'It's numeric'
    END
```

So far, I'm betting nothing. Am I missing anything?

Comment: `PRINT 'It''s numeric'`

Comment: or you can use SELECT 'It''s numeric'

Comment: Can "Five", "pi", "XLII", "0xDEADBEEF", "6.02E+23", "12.345,67" or "1+1" be converted to numeric values? `ISNUMERIC` is not as dependable as most users would like. For example, [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/302466/isnumeric-returns-true-for-and) and [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/01/13/isnumeric-broken-only-up-to-a-point/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've got a quoting issue in your print statement

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(50)
SET @var1 = '1'

IF(ISNUMERIC(@var1) = 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'It is numeric'
    END
```

Comment: I'm surprised that sql server failed so silently. Normally, it's complaint for anything.