# How to echo php array in html5 audio and video players?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, html

I have two php arrays, array a contain strings representing paths for mp3 files on server. Array b contains strings representing paths for mp4 files.

Lets take this simple example

```
$test = 'a.mp3';
$var = json_encode($test);
echo '<audio controls>';
echo '<source src=<?php $var ?> type="audio/mpeg">';
echo 'Your browser does not support the audio element.';
echo '</audio>';
```

this didn't work. This didn't work either

```
$test = 'a.mp3';
$var = json_encode($test);
echo '<audio controls>';
echo '<source src=$var type="audio/mpeg">';
echo 'Your browser does not support the audio element.';
echo '</audio>';
```

With quotes, without quotes, nothing works. I even tried without `json_encode` and didn't work obviously. so how to echo variables into html5 players? I will then be able to loop through the array, generating a playlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $test = 'a.mp3';
 $var = json_encode($test);
echo '<audio controls>';
echo "<source src=$var type='audio/mpeg'>";
echo 'Your browser does not support the audio element.';
echo '</audio>';
```

Use double quote when you want to print the variable

Comment: so its double quotes before the source! and i stayed awake till 4 am trying to fix it. i hate programming, i hate my life, why did i choose this buggy career

Answer (score 2):

variables don't expand inside single `'` quotes, only inside double `"` quotes, (unless the single quotes are ultimately inside double quotes) so your second approach should have almost worked:

```
$test = 'a.mp3';
$var = json_encode($test);
echo '<audio controls>';
echo "<source src=$var type='audio/mpeg'>";
echo 'Your browser does not support the audio element.';
echo '</audio>';
```

However, I don't understand why you're JSON encoding the file name. If the `a.mp3` is in the same folder as this file, then just:

```
$test = 'a.mp3';
echo '<audio controls>';
echo "<source src='$test' type='audio/mpeg'>";
echo 'Your browser does not support the audio element.';
echo '</audio>';
```

Comment: I have to `json_encode`, in this particular example it is in the same folder but that's not always the case. and I copy pasted your example, didn't work

Comment: ah ok, that explains why you JSON encoded it now. I had added single quotes around the src variable because of that. I removed those.

Comment: now it will work, it's double quote before the source, i just accepted the guy with a lower rep, because he said it first and to encourage him to give more answers!

Comment: i just wanna cry so bad, double quotes had me trying to fix it till 4 am, i want to quit programming right now

Comment: @Lynob don't be so hard on yourself - it's a common problem, I'd bet money there's on average 1 quotes-related question on SO everyday. [here's my same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36852007/4233593) to this question less than a month ago, and [here's one I answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37471187/4233593) just earlier today for an SQL statement. You gotta feel the burn to learn, and at least now you know. bonus: bash uses these same rules for quoted variable expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrays = array(
    'mp3' => 'http://example.com/file/filename.mp3',
    'mp4' => 'http://example.com/file/filename.mp4',
);

echo '<audio controls>';
echo '<source src='.$arrays['mp3'].' type="audio/mpeg">';
echo 'Your browser does not support the audio element.';
echo '</audio>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In php you are not allowed to make the php open tag `<?php` again.
for this line `echo '<source src=<?php $var ?> type="audio/mpeg">';` you should just make code like this `echo '<source src="$var" type="audio/mpeg">';`